# How to retrieve all dependencies from my project

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

How to retrieve all `jar` dependencies from my eclipse project using ANT Task, I need the names/and paths of all `jars` to run the current eclipse project?

I will add all libraries to a custom folder when to do package of my project.

Comment: retrieve from where...? you have maven tagged, are you talking about maven dependencies? and what does "when to do package" mean, maven packaging or something else?

Comment: i'm to do a custom projects packages without maven, only with ANT tasks, and then i thinking to retrieve the all jars dependences of my eclipse projects to copy these dependences to my customs folders.

Comment: I really don't understand what's being asked, but dependency management in Ant sounds like a job for [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)

Comment: i dont want to manage dependecies, i want retrieve a list of dependencies/jars names of my project.

Answer (score 3):

You should add all your JAR files into a single lib directory and add it to your `build.xml`.

Another approach would be adding your jars into a single JAR file.

Comment: sounds good but actually, I have done a project with maven and eclipse then not all my dependencies are in the build.xml

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a rough idea. It basically parses Eclipse's `.classpath` file and produces a file with all JAR dependency names line by line.

```
<project name="test" default="test">
  <target name="test">
    <copy file=".classpath" tofile="jars.txt" overwrite="true">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern="classpathentry"/>
            </linecontainsregexp>           
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern=".*path=&quot;" replace=""/>
                <replaceregex pattern="&quot;.*" replace=""/>
            </tokenfilter>          
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern=".*\.jar"/>
            </linecontainsregexp>                       
        </filterchain>
    </copy> 
  </target>
</project>
```